# how to do restart a AudioBufferSourceNode?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I cannot find in the WebAudio API (http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/) a way to restart  an `AudioBufferSourceNode`. The “loop” mode is not appropriate as I need to restart the node before it ends.

I have tried to implement it by doing:

1. stop
2. recreate the node from the buffer
3. start

But then there is a fraction of second with no sound making the transition not smooth.

What is the best way to restart an `AudioBufferSourceNode`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) you can't restart a buffersourcenode.  They're a one shot deal - once they're stopped, you need to throw them away and create a new one (pointing to the same AudioBuffer).

2) You need to plan ahead, in order to get the playback restarted at the same time that you've stopped it.  Javascript is not a real-time language, so the playback is happening on a different thread.

3) If you're just trying to get close, but still overlapping, you may want to put envelopes on the ending and beginning to smooth the transitions - e.g. use setTargetAtTime to ramp a gain value up (at the beginning) and down (at the stop time).

Comment: Is there another way (in addition to `AudioBufferSourceNode`) to plug a pcm array into the audio graph?

Comment: another question: I understand that it is impossible seek an `AudioBufferSourceNode`. What is the rationale behind it?

Comment: You can't really "plug a PCM array in" - but you could use a ScriptProcessor, I suppose.  It's not a great solution right now, due to latency.  Seriously, though, these are not critical limitations of the BufferSourceNode - they're limitations of Javascript.  There should not be any fraction of a second with no sound making the transition not smooth.  If you send me an example, I can take a look.

Comment: You can't seek a buffer source node mostly because it's not totally predictable when that seek would happen; the goal was to create a low-enough level API that you can create anything, not give all possible high-level constructs.  For example, I do seeking and all kinds of things in my DJ demo - http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/wubwubwub/.  (Click the power button on a deck, then click in the sound file display.)

Comment: Since you recommend throwing away the `AudioBufferSourceNode`, is it worthwhile to call `disconnect()` on it after the audio is done playing? Additionally, I have an "ended" event listener. Would GC clean up all the instances and events once they've been replaced?

Comment: If you’re not holding any refs to the AudiobufferSourceNode, it will get GCed some time after it’s done playing.

Answer (score 0):

> The “loop” mode is not appropriate as I need to restart the node before it ends

There actually are [loopEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/loopEnd) and [loopStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/loopStart) properties in the AudioBufferSourceNode, so you *can* restart the node before it ends.

```
// say you want to restart node every time it reaches 2.3 seconds
var node = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
node.buffer = getSomeAudioBuffer('someSound.mp3');
node.connect(audioCtx.destination);
node.loopEnd = 2.3;
node.loop = true;
node.start();
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/klesun/nL7ry76n/5/)